# How to use right join correctly

Tags: mysql, sql

Table Locations

```
loc_id  loc_name        hier2   hier3   hier4   hier5   hier6   hier7   hier8   hier9   
152675  Castelli        105     109     0       319     14356   152673  152675  0   
14356   Rome            105     109     0       319     14356   0       0       0       
...
```

Table Lacations References

```
oid     name        loc_id
12      Demo Villa  152675
...
```

Now i try to find some entries a user searches by entering the string "caste":

```
SELECT geo.loc_id, geo.loc_name AS name
FROM locations AS geo  
LEFT JOIN locations AS geoh3 ON geo.hier3 = geoh3.loc_id  
LEFT JOIN locations AS geoh4 ON geo.hier4 = geoh4.loc_id  
LEFT JOIN locations AS geoh8 ON geo.hier8 = geoh8.loc_id    
WHERE geo.loc_name LIKE 'caste%'
GROUP BY geo.loc_name
```

This works. I get the entry with loc_id 152675

Now i only want to get those entrys we have objects in. So i join the reference table:

```
SELECT geo.loc_id, geo.loc_name AS name
FROM locations AS geo  
LEFT JOIN locations AS geoh3 ON geo.hier3 = geoh3.loc_id  
LEFT JOIN locations AS geoh4 ON geo.hier4 = geoh4.loc_id  
LEFT JOIN locations AS geoh8 ON geo.hier8 = geoh8.loc_id  
RIGHT JOIN locations_xref AS gx ON geo.loc_id = gx.loc_id 
WHERE geo.loc_name LIKE 'caste%'
GROUP BY geo.loc_name
```

This works. Again i get the location entry with loc_id 152675 because theres a reference.

**PROBLEM**

Now the user searches for "rome". I dont get any entry because there is no object reference directly to the city "Rome". The existing object is referenced to a district of rome.

As you can see the district and the city entries have hierarchy IDs which can be used to identify the correct structure. I just cant get it to work together with the reference table, so i only get those objects which are in "rome" or in a district, which is part of rome.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question, but why `name` in the Location References table is different from `loc_name` in `Locations` for the same `loc_id`? Are they actually supposed to be identical or is it all right that they are different? Basically, I'm just not sure I understand what the References table is for.

Comment: The "name" field in the reference table refers to the name of an real estate object. So it has nothing to do with the geographical locations.

Comment: The `hier2` .. `hier9` columns suggest a sub-optimal de-normalized table form that makes your queries complex and slow.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about your data but from first sight it seems that `hier6` has the information about relationship between **Rome** and **Castelli**. So the query you need may look something more or less like this:

```
SELECT geo.loc_id, geo.loc_name AS name
FROM locations AS geo  
LEFT JOIN locations AS geoh3 ON geo.hier3 = geoh3.loc_id  
LEFT JOIN locations AS geoh6 ON geo.hier6 = geoh6.loc_id  
LEFT JOIN locations AS geoh4 ON geo.hier4 = geoh4.loc_id  
LEFT JOIN locations AS geoh8 ON geo.hier8 = geoh8.loc_id  
RIGHT JOIN locations_xref AS gx ON geo.loc_id = gx.loc_id 
WHERE geoh6.loc_name LIKE 'rome%'
GROUP BY geo.loc_name
```

Comment: Useful for pointing out the the OP how his own hierarchy works. I don't think this will give him what he wants, but it's definitely a step in the right direction.

Comment: Thats what i allready had, but it didnt work for me. Found another solution today splitting the query into two parts. Its faster too. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can tweak your query (as Karolis suggested), but I don't think that will give you what you want. Your query will return 'Castelli' when you search for 'Rome%', but it won't return 'Rome'. It won't return 'Rome', because 'Rome' isn't in your xref table.

To return 'Rome' with this kind of query, you'll need to insert a row for 'Rome' into the xref table.

You can get all the things that are "in" Rome with a UNION, but it doesn't reference your xref table at all.

```
select la.loc_id, la.loc_name
from locations la
where la.loc_name like 'Rome%'
union 
select lb.loc_id, lb.loc_name
from locations lb
inner join locations lc on lc.hier6 = lb.hier6
```

It's not clear to me how you determine which column to use for the join at run time.

**Later . . .**

If you don't know which columns to use at run time, you have to LEFT JOIN on all of them. And since you don't know whether the search string might refer to a value joined through column hier2, hier3, hier4, etc., then you have to check each of those columns for a match, too.

If locations_xref acts like a filter, then you need an inner join on that table, along with a row for 'Rome'. (Because you have properties in Rome.) Probably something along these lines.

```
SELECT geo.loc_id, geo.loc_name AS name
FROM locations AS geo  
LEFT JOIN locations AS geoh2 ON geo.hier2 = geoh2.loc_id  
LEFT JOIN locations AS geoh3 ON geo.hier3 = geoh3.loc_id  
LEFT JOIN locations AS geoh4 ON geo.hier4 = geoh4.loc_id  
LEFT JOIN locations AS geoh5 ON geo.hier5 = geoh5.loc_id  
LEFT JOIN locations AS geoh6 ON geo.hier6 = geoh6.loc_id  
LEFT JOIN locations AS geoh7 ON geo.hier7 = geoh7.loc_id  
LEFT JOIN locations AS geoh8 ON geo.hier8 = geoh8.loc_id  
LEFT JOIN locations AS geoh9 ON geo.hier9 = geoh9.loc_id  
INNER JOIN locations_xref lx on lx.loc_id = geo.loc_id
WHERE   geo.loc_name LIKE 'Rom%' 
   or geoh2.loc_name like 'Rom%'
   or geoh3.loc_name like 'Rom%'
   or geoh4.loc_name like 'Rom%'
   or geoh5.loc_name like 'Rom%'
   or geoh6.loc_name like 'Rom%'
   or geoh7.loc_name like 'Rom%'
   or geoh8.loc_name like 'Rom%'
   or geoh9.loc_name like 'Rom%'
```

Before you get too invested in this model, you should take a look at [Bill Karwin's database antipatterns](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back). "Naive Trees" starts on slide 48.

Comment: Every "hierX" column refers to a deeper geographical hierarchy. So if someone searches for "Rome" every hierarchy column should be searched, because there is a city called "Rome" and maybe a small hier8 place called "Romena". Your right about not returning "Rome" when searching for "Rome". I dont get your answer. Could you explain it better please?

Comment: A "Pizzaria" will not be returned, because the Locations only contain  geographical locations like Cities, Districts, Regions aso.

Comment: A query like that i allready had. The Question was how can i exclude locations which contain no objects. 
I tried it with `RIGHT JOIN locations_xref AS gx ON geo.loc_id = gx.loc_id`

Comment: What does "a location that contains no objects" mean (in terms of tables and rows) in this database?

Comment: There are lots of locations in the (geo)database, which have no real estate objects referenced. The reference table `location_xref` contains all references between geo-locations and real estate object IDs.

Comment: But when you search for Rome, you want the database to return all the real estate object ids for Castelli. Is that right?

Comment: No, i wanna get the locations the objects are in. Not the objects themselves.

Comment: @Mike: Just an inner join, then, I think. See changes above.